# How to execute test for each custom attribute and each test data combination

Tags: c#, xunit

How to execute test for each custom attribute and each test data combination.
In my example there should be four test cases:

- [User("A")] with ("test1", 1)
- [User("A")] with ("test2", 2)
- [User("B")] with ("test1", 1)
- [User("B")] with ("test2", 2)

But **User** is not used in test. I need "**user**" in Initialize method

```
public class ExapmleTest
{
    [User("A")]
    [User("B")]
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("test1", 1)]
    [InlineData("test2", 2)]
    public void ExapmleTest1(string testInput, int count)
    {
        // Test body
    }
}
```

For now I did something like below. It "work" and create four test cases but two of them have the same input data so at the and xunit remove two  "duplicated" testcases.

```
public class UserAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UserAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("xxx", "xxx")] // you need to put your assembly
public class MyTheoryAttribute : TheoryAttribute
{ }

public class TestCaseTheoryDiscoverer : IXunitTestCaseDiscoverer
{
    readonly TheoryDiscoverer theoryDiscoverer;
    private readonly IMessageSink _diagnosticMessageSink;

    public IMessageSink DiagnosticMessageSink => _diagnosticMessageSink;

    public TestCaseTheoryDiscoverer(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink)
    {
       theoryDiscoverer = new TheoryDiscoverer(diagnosticMessageSink);
       _diagnosticMessageSink = diagnosticMessageSink;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IXunitTestCase> Discover(ITestFrameworkDiscoveryOptions discoveryOptions, ITestMethod testMethod, IAttributeInfo factAttribute)
    {
         var userAttributes = testMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserAttribute)).ToList();

         var inlineDataAttributes = testMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InlineDataAttribute)).ToList();

            foreach (var userAttribute in userAttributes)
            {
                foreach (var inlineDataAttribute in inlineDataAttributes)
                {
                    var userAttributeData = userAttribute.GetConstructorArguments().FirstOrDefault();
                    var constructorArgsArray = inlineDataAttribute.GetConstructorArguments().ToArray();
                    var constructorArgs = (object[])constructorArgsArray[0];

                    var testCase = new MyTestCase(_diagnosticMessageSink, TestMethodDisplay.ClassAndMethod, TestMethodDisplayOptions.None, testMethod, userAttribute, constructorArgs.Cast<object>().ToArray());

                    yield return testCase;
                }
            }
        }

public class ExapmleTest
{
    [User("A")]
    [User("B")]
    [MyTheory]
    [InlineData("test1", 1)]
    [InlineData("test2", 2)]
    public void ExapmleTest1(string testInput, int count)
    {
        // Test body
    }
}
```

also tried write my TestCase which have **UserAttribute** but if I use MyTestCase in TestCaseTheoryDiscoverer then xunit do not find any tests after build.

```
public class MyTestCase : XunitTestCase
{
    public IAttributeInfo _userAttribute;

    public MyTestCase() { }

    public MyTestCase(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink, TestMethodDisplay defaultMethodDisplay, TestMethodDisplayOptions defaultMethodDisplayOptions,
        ITestMethod testMethod, IAttributeInfo userAttribute, object[] testMethodArguments)
        : base(diagnosticMessageSink, defaultMethodDisplay, defaultMethodDisplayOptions, testMethod, testMethodArguments)
    {
        _userAttribute = userAttribute;
    }

    public override void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo data)
    {
        base.Serialize(data);
        data.AddValue("UserAttribute", _userAttribute);
    }

    public override void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo data)
    {
        base.Deserialize(data);
        _userAttribute = data.GetValue<IAttributeInfo>("UserAttribute");
    }

    protected override string GetDisplayName(IAttributeInfo factAttribute, string displayName)
    {
        var userAttributeValue = _userAttribute.GetConstructorArguments().First();
        return $"{base.GetDisplayName(factAttribute, displayName)} ({userAttributeValue})";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, if you want to get the `UserAttribute` inside the test you can simply pass it in the inline data and then construct it inside the test.
`[InlineData("test1", "A")] void ExapmleTest1(string testInput, string attributeName)`

And then `var attribute = new UserAttribute(attributeName);`

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with custom attributes:

```
public class UnitTest
{
    [Theory]
    [GenerateDataCombinationsAttribute]
    public void Test(
       [Values(1, 2)] int param1, 
       [Values(3, 4)] int param2)
    {
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ValuesAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly object[] _values;

    public ValuesAttribute(params object[] values) => _values = values;

    public object[] GenerateValues() => _values;
}

public class GenerateDataCombinationsAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod) => 
        Generate(GenerateValueSets(testMethod));

    private static IEnumerable<object[]> Generate(object[][] sets)
    {
        if (sets.Length == 1)
        {
            foreach (var value in sets[0])
            {
                yield return new[] { value };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var otherValuesCartesianProduct = Generate(sets.Skip(1).ToArray());
            foreach (var value in sets[0])
            {
                foreach (var otherValues in otherValuesCartesianProduct)
                {
                    yield return new[] { value }.Concat(otherValues).ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private object[][] GenerateValueSets(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var parameter = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        var result = new object[parameter.Length][];
        for (var i = 0; i < parameter.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = GenerateValueSets(parameter[i]);
        }
        return result;

        object[] GenerateValueSets(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
        {
            var valueSet = new List<object>();
            foreach (var attribute in parameterInfo.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
                var valueGenerator = attribute as ValuesAttribute;
                if (valueGenerator != null)
                {
                    valueSet.AddRange(valueGenerator.GenerateValues());
                }
            }
            return valueSet.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Some details:

1. You should define a new custom attribute where you will provide fields that should be used to generate output combinations.
2. You should define a new DataAttribute implementation (`GenerateDataCombinationsAttribute` ) that will be responsible for final output combinations
3. As output, the test configuration I provided above will generate 4 different test cases.
4. As I know, it's not possible to use just `InlineData` for this target